# how to upgrade hadoop on existing cluster - google cloud

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

the question is self-contained. I deployed some cluster and now I want to upgrade my hadoop version. I tried to check the `bdutil` or `gsutil`, I didn't find how to make it work !

Comment: I got the advise of a google engeneer - in fact this feature seems not to be supported -

Comment: I'll re-summarize as an actual answer in case others have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, since the various paths, library dependencies, and daemon processes are fairly different between Hadoop 1 and Hadoop 2, there's no easy way to upgrade in-place right now. In particular, any customizations made to the cluster are likely to break even if the library upgrades and daemon changes are coordinated, so in general, it's much easier and safer to simply delete and recreate the cluster.

To help prevent getting overly stuck on a single cluster instance and benefit from the agility of being able to re-deploy reproducible clusters from scratch, the best-practice recommendation is to isolate any customizations you might have into custom "_env.sh" files. The [spark_env.sh extension](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/blob/master/extensions/spark/spark_env.sh) is a good example of how to mix in extra customizations on top of an existing bdutil installation. For another example, if you simply want to install `openjdk-7-jdk` on all machines at the end of a bdutil installation, you'd create files `install_jdk.sh` and `add_jdk_env.sh`:

```
# file: install_jdk.sh

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

And for add_jdk_env.sh:

```
# file: add_jdk_env.sh

# Create a command group which references the new install_jdk.sh file.
COMMAND_GROUPS+=(
  "install_jdk:
     install_jdk.sh
  "
)

# Run that command group on master and workers.
COMMAND_STEPS+=(
  'install_jdk,install_jdk'
)
```

And finally, you simply mix it in for your bdutil deployment: `./bdutil -e add_jdk_env.sh deploy`